# Is there an Windows Phone repository like Cocoa Controls?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, windows-phone-8, controls

I'm looking for a repository for Windows Phone sample apps and controls like http://www.cocoacontrols.com/ fo iOs, is there one similar?

Answer (score 0):

Two popular repositories are http://coding4fun.codeplex.com and http://phone.codeplex.com. The latter is maintained by the Windows Phone development team and contains controls that did not make it to the SDK (yet).